# Differences Between Flex SDK and Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

Can Anyone tell me the differences between Flex SDK and Flash Builder ??

Like - "Mobile development using Adobe Flex SDK "Hero" and Flash Builder "Burrito"

Are Both same ?? Please clarify in details. We understand that Flex is an IDE or SDK(software development kit ) where we build,compile and deploy projects with sets of components and class library available .

Previously it was clear that Adobe Flex builder 3 has been renamed to Adobe Flash Builder 4 like that.

I am really confused. Can anyone help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

Flash Builder Burrito is the next version of Flash Builder (formerly Flex Builder).  It's an IDE used to help write Flex applications.

Flex Hero is the next version of the Flex framework.  It provides the classes, components and compiler which form the building blocks of Flex applications.

Ie:  You can build Flex Hero applications by writing and editing code inside Flash Builder Burrito.

Comment: But not exclusively, it's worth mentioning. You can use any tool (from notepad on up) to write the Flex code. The compiler is effectively command line

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Flex Builder 3 and Flash Builder 4 are graphical user interfaces, an IDE.
At the same time there are many versions of flex, for example flex builder 3 introduced flex 3 sdk and Flash Builder 4 introduced flex 4 sdk... Those frameworks are open source so u can compile and develop an app using the sdk, that is not very simple because u will need to create you source code in a plain text editor, totally manual and compile from a command line... Flash builder 4 and Flex Builder are IDE but they are not open source and aren't free, so you will have have to pay or use a student license from adobe flash plattform